# How to identify a machine by its IP address in wireshark?

Tags: ip, wireshark, packet

I'm new to the world of security and I'm trying to figure out how to analyze the network traffic on my home wifi network. I've been watching a lot of tutorials and reading about how to use wireshark. I've identified that there is some traffic going to IP address 192.168.1.19(me) as well as my phone .20 but there is unexpected traffic coming from a device with IP address 192.168.1.15, and .4. Is there a way I can see the type of device or the device name just from knowing the IP so I can know what device to look for?

Comment: you need to use another tool to scan those addresses - like `nmap`

Comment: If it's windows, you can open cmd and try `nbtstat -a 192.168.1.15`.

Comment: I'm on mac. I have nmap downloaded and installed. I'm looking up how to use nmap. Thanks for the swift replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two approaches to solve you question:

- **Passive**: meaning that you don't want to interact with the device you want to discover. You can **monitor the network** using Wireshark and find information such as the **MAC address**, from MAC, you can know the device **manufacture**. Or by analyzing other requests.
- **Active**: in this case you can interact with the device and discover more about it but you may **raise an attention** by its owner. There are many tools you can use, I prefer [nmap](https://nmap.org/) which available on Windows and Linux.

Comment: Many devices allow changing the MAC address for over 30 years, but this is a starting point.

Comment: Correct. but it worths a shot.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to download nmap and gave both methods a try.